# 'int' object is not callable when calculating min

Tags: python, min, callable

I am having a very weird and frustrating error.

The problem is very simple:

```
>>> mylist
[70.71, 67.23, 60.1, 62.52, 64.14, 65.4, 68.84, 61.04, 66.95, 62.22, 63.73, 62.04, 57.12, 61.3, 65.48, 61.49, 66.94, 62.68, 60.31, 64.38, 62.84, 63.03, 67.12, 60.65, 61.68, 64.0, 62.91, 61.36, 60.65, 62.45, 64.22, 66.4, 59.96, 57.03, 66.4, 60.43, 64.05, 64.09, 50.94, 39.84, 45.12, 63.39, 55.62, 55.58, 58.04, 59.91, 60.05, 57.3, 61.83, 63.87, 50.58, 62.56, 60.75, 58.9, 62.99, 61.65, 59.09, 59.91, 64.66, 61.1, 61.31, 59.62, 56.65, 60.1, 66.04, 60.57, 59.77, 53.0, 60.84, 61.75, 64.53, 52.0, 62.08, 67.69, 60.62, 55.04, 54.49, 30.82, 48.32, 59.66, 62.56, 66.71, 70.4, 55.13, 59.32, 63.06, 56.0, 56.19, 65.9, 61.01, 62.03, 59.43, 62.82, 56.83, 62.91, 76.44, 68.01, 61.0, 63.51, 58.12, 65.77, 56.88, 63.18, 69.03, 63.34, 54.91, 60.25, 64.79, 64.17, 61.86, 53.05, 63.42, 57.08, 60.36, 59.62, 64.69, 59.78, 58.34, 65.19, 55.49, 73.53, 56.25, 61.09, 53.35, 63.45, 64.34, 29.79, 59.75, 67.7, 59.74, 52.17, 61.29, 58.88, 55.68, 55.81, 57.52, 62.0, 62.49, 60.47, 61.86, 56.94, 56.31, 61.82, 62.01, 59.99, 59.4, 57.9, 63.08, 64.56, 60.77, 63.95, 60.1, 66.22, 58.05, 66.25, 62.34, 61.17, 64.04, 64.08, 61.1, 56.19, 61.04, 53.13, 64.58, 60.96, 58.97, 59.43, 66.22, 58.4, 55.68, 35.47, 42.6, 57.57, 58.3, 60.84, 62.52, 54.86, 60.9, 60.99, 60.47, 61.45, 58.34, 62.17, 63.68, 62.4, 64.62, 56.78, 59.14, 61.47, 54.7, 55.3, 58.09, 62.95, 61.47, 57.69, 62.45, 54.86, 58.51, 60.52, 54.56]
```

An now I try to get the min value:

```
>>> min(mylist)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Why?

Comment: I can not reproduce this. `min(mylist)` returns `29.79`.

Comment: I can get the same result but just doing like this: `mylist = numpy.array(mylist)` and `mylist.min()`

Comment: @newPyUser: or you can do `del min` to delete the assignment that masks the built-in.

Comment: Don't put answers in the question; accept an existing answer or write your own.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most probably you have a variable named `min` that shadowed the built in min function. If you are using the interactive console just do:

```
del min
```

Also consider using numpy, as it can be faster on bigger lists:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.min(mylist)
```

Comment: Technically the function isn't overwritten but shadowed (i.e. the function is in builtins, and the int is in locals or globals).

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce this. `min(mylist)` returns `29.79`.

You are probably using a variable called `min` in your code. Don't do this.